# Why is their no object instance in front of the findViewById() method in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, findviewbyid

I'm new to programming and I'm following the Android Kotlin basics codelabs. There is one thing I don't understand.

In Android developing, to connect the (Kotlin) code to the UI XML you can use the `findViewById()` method. For example, to reference a Button in the UI from your code you can use: `val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)`. As you can see this [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-create-dice-roller-app-with-button#4).

In my understanding, a method can only be called from an object instance. So why is their no object instance in front of the `findViewById()` method? Like one of the exmples below:

```
val rollButton: Button = rollButton.findViewById(R.id.button)
val rollButton: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.button)
```

Answer (score 1):

FindViewById is a method found in AppCompatActivity (Activities) which is why you're able to call it from an activity directly, if you stop inheriting from `AppCompatActivity` (or something similar), you won't be able to access it anymore.

Similarly, for `FindViewById` being called from a view in your example `rollButton.findViewById`, well, there you do have an instance of an object, in your case it's a `View` called rollButton, which (hopefully) points to an instance of an object

Comment: Also when you call ``findViewById``, you're really calling ``this.findViewById``, and when you're in an ``Activity``'s scope that means you're calling it on an ``Activity`` instance. It's just that Java and Kotlin allow you to omit ``this`` since it's implied